# how to use robot framework to open iterm then run a node --version and check the result

Tags: macos, robotframework, iterm2

I am researching robotic process automation (RPA) under MacOS. I come across [Robot Framework](https://robotframework.org/#documentation) There's some [suggestion](https://medium.com/@joshua.gorospe/turn-your-test-teams-automation-into-monitoring-and-alerting-using-robot-framework-rpa-and-fa4fdf841591) that it can be used for RPA but the documentation I found pertains mostly to web apps.

My use case is not for web apps.

It works like this:

1. turn on iterm2
2. run a command like `node --version`
3. then check the output

Is there a way to do this series of actions as automation using Robot Framework or any other kind of library?

Answer (score 0):

RF could be extended by libraries. The one library you might be looking for is [Process](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html).

I don't have iterm2, but I can try the second and third step.

First, you need to import the library:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Process
```

and define your desired test case:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Check Node Version
    ${result}=    Run Process    node    --version    
    Should Be Equal    v14.3.0    ${result.stdout}
```

`${result}` will be an object, you can access various properties such as stdout, stderr etc., see [docs](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Result%20object)